# Bone is deforming vertexes but shouldn't

Tags: armature, bones

I prepared descriptions on the photos:
[image]
[image]
Vertices are assigned well:
[image]

**What I would like to achieve is to move whole arm with keeping constant distances between vertices.**

I assigned only blue vertices, made minimum and maximum scale to 1.
I tried to turn off deforming but arm didn't track bone then.
I tried some other options but it was only random shots, I knew they shouldn't work.

File to download:
[image]

**I solved this issue:**
[image]

These 4 vertexes was added to the previous (selected) bone and it made a problem!
I removed them from selected bone and problem disappeared. I think I don't understand this system yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the *vertices in the vertex group* of that bone to adjust which vertices to be deformed by the bone, not a limit scale.

Do this, select the armature and <kbd>SHFT</kbd>+Select the mesh making sure that the mesh is the active object. Then go to edit mode, and on the right properties panel go to the vertex groups tab, and select the vertex group assigned to the bone of the character's arm. It should have the name of the bone.

Make sure no vertices are selected before selecting any vertex groups by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> once. Then select the vertex group for the bone.

The vertices assigned to that bone should appear. If some are showing up that you do not want to deform from that bone, deselect them.

After this, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to select inverse, and then press "Remove". This will then remove the vertices selected from that vertex group, so that they don't deform with that bone.

EDIT:

So I found the issue to be that you have an unnecessary bone in between the arm and the shoulder. By deleting this bone, the arm deforms properly.

[image]

Now the arm deforms properly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have written that vertices are assigned well. I edited my post and added screen with proof.

Comment: If you are willing could you add the file?

Comment: Ok, I added link to my google disc. It shouldn't disappear until Google is existing.

Comment: Ok, I solved issue. This arm bone has correct vertices. But previous bone didn't!
I contained also 4 selected (in my post in last screen) vertexes.
I didn't moved this bone but it was interfered with arm vertexes in any not know way for me.
Thanks for you advices, without them I wouldn't notice this.
Maybe you could write my solution so I could make your post as answer?
You can use my screenshot. Just write that previous bone is influencing this arm :-)